# What is the maximum number of items passed to IN() in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am given a bunch of IDs (from an external source) that I need to cross-reference with the ones on our database and filter out those that fall between a certain date and are also "enabled" and some other parameters. I can easily do this by doing:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` IN (csv_list_of_external_ids) 
    AND (my other cross-reference parameters);
```

And by doing this, of all those incoming IDs I will get the ones that I want. But obviously this is not a very efficient method when the external ids are in the thousands. And I'm not sure if MySQL will even support such a huge query.

Given that nothing can be cached (since both the user data and the external ids change pretty much on every query), and that these queries happen at least every 10 seconds. What other SQL alternatives are there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the only limit is the length of the actual query, which is controlled by the "max_allowed_packet" parameter in your my.cnf file.

Comment: The trouble is that I don't have control over that parameter.

Comment: Then you'll just need to make sure you keep your queries shorter than the limit that is set.  One way to do that might be to insert all of the values in your IN() clause into a temporary table, using multiple INSERT statements, then use a sub-select in your query:  WHERE `id` IN(SELECT id FROM temp_table)

Comment: By temporary table do you mean using MEMORY as the table's engine?

Comment: You could do it in memory, or on disk--whichever you prefer.  Memory is probably just as good, since your only goal is working around the max query size.

Comment: I just did some quick research on temporary tables and those are exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you express it as a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE id IN (SELECT ID FROM SOME_OTHER_TABLE)
AND ...
```

there is no limit.

Comment: My issue is that the IDs from the subquery are passed to me from an external source as a string (it's an API call from another provider)